# Do fractional derivatives maintain the $[fg]'=f'g+g'f$ and $f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$ rules?

Tags: fractional-calculus

Of course, I'm not really familiar with all fractional derivative methods, but is it a necessary rule that they all should comply with? 
If not, which ones, for example, do and which don't ?

( Specifically: I am interested in Caputo's fractional derivation method 
$$D^\alpha_+ f(x)=1/\Gamma(n-\alpha)\int^x_0(x-\zeta)^{n-\alpha-1}f^{(n)}(\zeta)d\zeta$$ 
where $n=[\alpha]+1$.

More info. : In Caputo's method, taking the half-derivatve of an exponential function is : 
$$D^{1/2}_+ \exp(kx)=k^{1/2}\exp(kx)*(1-\Gamma(1/2,kx)/\Gamma(1/2)).$$
Now, say I wish to take another derivative of the above, meaning  $$D^{1/2}_+ [D^{1/2}_+ \exp(kx)]=?.$$   Can I use the $[fg]'=f'g+g'f$ rule for that? Can I simply say $$D^{1/2}_+ D^{1/2}_+f(x)=f'(x) \implies D^{1/2}_+ D^{1/2}_+\exp(kx)=k*\exp(kx) ?$$ Or am I really in truble ?)

Comment: As far as I know, the most terrible issue of fractional derivatives is precisely that they do not obey the Leibnitz rule.

Comment: This paper may be a useful reference to you. See Remark 1 and the surrounding text.

http://www1.beuth-hochschule.de/~luchko/papers/FreedFordDiethelmLuchko.pdf

Comment: @JessicaK: Thanks for the paper. I'll go over it.

Comment: @JessicaK: See my last edit to the question, do I really need such a 'modified Leibniz rule' as the one that they suggest in the paper, for the case of consecutive derivation that I wrote above? Or is there a simpler way to calculate higher order fractional derivatives?

Answer (score 1):

For the second rule, no. For the first rule, yes, but it becomes infinite series rather than finite expression.